# How to check AutoStart is enabled for our App in Xiaomi manufacturer mobile device Programmatically

Tags: android, security, service, autostart

While working with ***Xiaomi*** manufactured mobile devices, I am opening **AutoStart** screen to enable AutoStart for my App. But is there any way to **check Is AutoStart is enabled** for our App.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: did you got any solution for this?

Comment: No Varun Bhardwaj

Comment: hi, Did you found any clue to check status of autostart.

Comment: @ShamiliRani there is no Android API to check if the the AutoStart is enabled or not. Though you can have you logic (may be you can use preference to set a Boolean for it) to check this. Please have a look here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/56335831/5685911